# Create/Drop Tables in Athena using Alteryx Designer

Tags: alteryx, amazon-athena

is there way to drop and create tables in Athena from Alteryx Designer? I thought it would be dead simple using the connect In DB node and writing

```
drop table test
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Connect In-DB (3)   Error SQLPrepare: [Simba][Athena] (1040) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Athena Error No: 130, HTTP Response Code: 400, Exception Name: InvalidRequestException, Error Message: line 1:30: mismatched input 'drop'. Expecting: '(', 'LATERAL', 'UNNEST', <identifier> [Execution ID: ]
```

Is there a way to it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Athena Bulk Loader in Output Data tool.
This has functionality you need.
Data Connections > Amazon Athena > Bulk

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the connect In DB node and writing a drop query is not allowed... only select type queries are allowed.
(and by the way,Athena is not supported for in database, cf [Ideas to support Athena](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Desktop-Ideas/Need-In-DB-support-for-Athena/idi-p/1214800)

So you must use standard output tool with a bulk load
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KVVk.png)

Best regards,

Simon